# Xcode test navigator stuck on spinner using KIF tests

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, integration, kif

I am writing integration tests for my iOS app using KIF with the latest Xcode 5.  When I run a test, a suite of tests, or all of them, the tests pass with no errors according to the console log, but the test navigator either takes many minutes to show the green pass icon for simple tests like Login, or keeps the spinner running indefinitely. I frequently have to Force Quit Xcode in order to clear the test results. I see this both on the simulator and the device.

I have tried using [tester waitForTimeInterval:3.0]; at the end of each test to no avail.

I have not found any discussions or solutions in all my searches, so I'm hoping to get some answers on this one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scott Anderson of Walmart Labs for this tip.

The cause of the slow test resolution was NSLog().  I have my own macro version that activates logs when compiled for Debug, which is the case for the Test builds.  I log the output of all my server calls, which adds up especially during the registration process.  When I disabled that, my tests came back green right after finishing, and no more hanging spinner.

The test navigator must be parsing the console output for XCTest result, slowly.  This is my speculation, but would explain the slowness.